# VS Code setting issue? Voice Keyword Activation: How to disable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, accessibility

I am seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrQf6.png) being turned on at start up and will not disappear.

The tool in question is called 'Voice Keyword Activation', and I tried googling about this tool for vscode, but did not find any useful information.

Upon hovering, the message 'Waiting for voice chat to end...' and upon clicking, it will lead me to Settings tab with 'accessibility.voice.keywordActivation', which does not seem to exist in my settings.json. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8KFL.png) is what I see on Settings tab.

Anyone know how might I disable this?

Thank you!

I have disabled Editor Accessibility to 'off' already. My next guess was AudioCue, but there is no disabling this.

Comment: This weirded me out a bit as well. Add this to your JSON settings file to disable it `"accessibility.voice.keywordActivation": "off"`. It will say the configuration is unknown, but it should disable it anyway. If not, let me know.

Comment: This should work as well! Thank you. Not sure why this issue is popping up to some of us..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also mysteriously appeared for me, so I looked in to it. It's because it expects this extension to be installed:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-speech

When I installed this, the icon disappeared.

Comment: This is it! Thank you! I thought I researched it thoroughly... Where was this solution?

Comment: It was a guess on my part, I think because I've had a similar issue in the past with a missing extension and I was getting deja vu, ha. It was also because some of the copilot integration has been a bit messy, so I thought it might have something to do with that.